# Can't access localhost - no permission

Tags: localhost, wamp

I have problem accessing localhost (127.0.0.1) with chrome and internet explorer, but have no such problem with firefox and opera..

When I try to access 127.0.0.1, I got this message:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server

I have tried reinstalling wamp server but up to no avail.

Is there any setting i should change to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to try:

1. Ping the IP address from a command prompt. If you can do that, then it doesn't sound like a WAMP Server issue.
2. Go into the document root for the default site, and put a file called `test.html`. Then in the browser, visit 'http://127.0.0.1/test.html'. Put a bit of content in there - e.g. `<p>Hello world</p>`. If you can visit it in Firefox but not Chrome or IE, then it's not a site configuration problem.
3. Disable IPv6. I have seen some issues with this on Windows.

Comment: i can ping the ip, i put hello.html on document root and can access it through firefox and opera but chrome give me `Not Found` message.i dont know how to disable IPv6 since there is no local area connection under Control Panel > Network and Internet

Comment: @slier See http://superuser.com/questions/174715/is-there-a-way-to-disable-ipv6-in-googles-chrome

Comment: I think the question is too broad to be solved by anything other than hoping that you randomly stumble on the right solution. Look at the WAMPServer Apache logs, and post any insight it gives you. Also, have you tried using something other than WAMP Server? e.g. EasyPHP, XAMPP, VMWare, VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works for me:

- Click on the Wamp server icon in the Notification area (Taskbar).
- Scroll down and select "Put Online".
- Your server will restart automatically.
- Try to access the localhost again.

Credit for http://en.kioskea.net/faq/28449-wamp-server-error-message-forbidden-you-don-t-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server